# Ubuntu 18.04 Repeat Keys wont stay off

Tags: 18.04

Repeat keys wont stay off in Ubuntu. I turn it off in the settings and it just turns itself back on after 10-15 minutes. I turn it off and after 10-15 minutes its on, but in the settings it still says it is off but it isn't off.

Comment: Please show the command you used to turn off repeat keys. Also why is repeat keys a problem? Most people enjoy this feature.....................

Comment: I turned it off in ubuntu settings. I turn it off because if its on while im playing games the games register each key repeat as one click of the button so my character studders around making it impossible to play. I have already tried 'xset r off' it still turns back on

Answer (score 1):

I understand the gaming concerns. Use this command:

```
$ gsettings list-recursively | grep top.peripherals.keyboard
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.keyboard repeat-interval uint32 30
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.keyboard delay uint32 500
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.keyboard repeat true
```

To turn off keyboard repeat use:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.keyboard repeat false
```

To get the current setting use:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.keyboard repeat
```

If something is making it `true` again after 10 to 15 minutes you can set the delay from 1/2 second to 5 seconds with:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.keyboard delay 5000
```

That should suffice for gaming I hope.

Comment: Thank you this helped

Comment: @Jark If it solved the problem click the grey check mark next to answer so others know it works. Thanks.